# Adding multiple menus entries to a view

Tags: views, routes

We have a view with a page attached to it. By default the settings screen pictured below lets you add only a single menu entry for the view.

Is it possible to have this featured in two or more menus as menu links?

[image: Page configuration from a view]

Comment: You can add link to multiple menus by navigating to "admin/structure/menu" and click on add link next to menu to which you would like to add .. View Menu setting is just to make your life easy so that you can configure directly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add as many menu items as you like in the menu administration section of the website.

1. Go to admin/structure/menu
2. Click the "add link" link for the menu you want to add an item to
3. Add the menu item to the path you are using for you view.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that menu entries become unlinked from the view. If the URL of the view changes, the menu entry is removed.

Comment: Unfortunately that's just how it is. Generally it is not that difficult to keep track of your views and their menu items and I would expect view paths would not change very frequently. Usually only users who know what they're doing deal with administering views so I don't see it as that much of an issue.